# jQuery how to make delayed appending inside a loop?

Tags: jquery, append, delay

Would like to append rows in a small period.

Couldn't do that. :)

Maybe someone here could demonstrate that?

Would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use window.setTimeout as described [here on the mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't knew there is third parameter for setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, something like this:

```
var timer = 0;
var items = $(".item").hide().each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    timer += 250;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        el.show();
    }, timer)
});
```

Comment: Not actually what i needed, but anyway thanks for timer logic. Forgot that loop don't wait for timeout. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).

Example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // this will be executed every 1000ms
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yea, but setInterval won't wait for completion of previous action.